# Dependent events

Tags: probability

In a well known website gives the following example as an example of 'Dependent' events:
".. tree diagrams are really wonderful for figuring out dependent events (where an event depends on what happens in the previous event) like this example:

Example: Soccer Game

You are off to soccer, and love being the Goalkeeper, but that depends who is the Coach today:
•with Coach Sam the probability of being Goalkeeper is 0.5
•with Coach Alex the probability of being Goalkeeper is 0.3

Sam is Coach more often ... about 6 out of every 10 games (a probability of 0.6).
So, what is the probability you will be a Goalkeeper today?
The probability of getting Sam is 0.6, 
Now, if you get Sam, there is 0.5 probability of being Goalie

For the first "Sam ; Yes " branch of the Tree, the two probabilities are multiplied , 0.6 x 0.5 to get 0.3 as the probability of the combined event 'Sam - Yes'.

We are told that multiplication can be done only for 'independent events'.

Are the  coach selection and Goalie selection, independent or dependent?

Subramanyan

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication rule is: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)$.

Hence:
$$P(Goalie)=P(Goalie\cap Sam)+P(Goalie \cap Alex)=$$
$$P(Sam)\cdot P(Goalie|Sam)+P(Alex)\cdot P(Goalie|Alex)=$$
$$0.6\cdot 0.5+0.4\cdot 0.3=0.3+0.12=0.42.$$